# Is there any free mocking framework that can mock static methods and sealed classes?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, mocking

Typemock can do this but it is $799USD and that is a lot to pay for two features.

Please no conversations about avoiding using static and sealed things or encapsulating them. 
When using a large 3rd party API it is not possible and/or practical.

Thanks

Comment: Your 3rd party framework does not seem to consider testing. There are still companies which do not know what an interface is good for ...

Comment: You are correct stefan. Their response to testing is "create a database with you test data and then run your tests"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not really, but you can use Moq [Moq Download](http://code.google.com/p/moq/) or Rhino Mocks [Rhino Mocks Download](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2009/09/01/rhino-mocks-3.6.aspx) to wrap the static method and call in a virtual instance method in another class

[Mocking Static methods using Rhino.Mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540239/mocking-static-methods-using-rhino-mocks)

Comment: i regularly use this for the occasional case but the API I am dealing with at the moment has a very large surface area and it would be a pain to take this aproach.
Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I could find was: http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/stubs/

I admit to having not used it, but I thought yourself and others may find the link useful.