# Unit testing ProfileBase in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, unit-testing

I need to implement my own Profile properties and was going to inherit from System.Web.Profile.ProfileBase to achieve this.

What I don't understand is how to best unit test this Profile class in isolation without hitting the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I came across this situation today and found your question while trying to find an answer.

What I have ended up doing is wrapping up all calls to ProfileBase in a wrapper class, and mocking out the wrapper class using this
[pattern](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540239/mocking-static-methods-using-rhino-mocks)
which talks specifically about Rhino Mocks

Not sure this will help you as it was a few months ago now since you asked the question.

Comment: An example would be great.  Followed the link provided but they don't give an example either.

Comment: @shanabus Create IProfileCommon and copy prorties in your ProfileCommon which will inherit from both ProfileBase, IProfileCommon. Use IProfileCommon as parameters and then when saving it, cast it back to ProfileCommon.