# If a class has a single public entry point that takes everything it needs as parameters, should it be static?

Tags: c#, .net, static

I just finished coding a class, and realized that all of its public functionality is encapsulated in a single method.  It has no properties, no shared resources, and requires no constructor overload and handles disposal of anything it uses.  It looks something like this:

```
public class ReportGenerator
{
    public string GenerateReport(List<SomeClass> stuffToReportOn)
    {
        string fileName = String.Empty;
        using(var reportDs = CreateDataSet(stuffToReportOn))
        {
            //do the stuff with the third party tool that 
            //creates the report.
            //Construct the filename.
            //Save the report.
        }
        return fileName;
    }

    private TypedDataSetRequiredByThirdPartyLib CreateDataSet(List<SomeClass> reportItems)
    {
        //create the dataset, calling two other private methods
        //to build the tables/rows
    }
}
```

After I finished refactoring it, I realized that this class could be entirely static.  My question is, should it?  Should a class that encapsulates all of its functionality in one public method be made static?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No. and what are the expected benefits?

Far more important is the potential for errors. If in your class you declare a static variable, it'll only get initialised once, its value will persist and each call will potentially behave differently. Easily over-looked, this can be difficult to debug.

Answer (score 3):

No, it will make writing unit tests for this class - or classes that use this class - impossible.

With a tool like [FakeItEasy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/53346/open-source-advertising-sidebar-2h-2010/59827#59827), you don't even need the class to implement an interface to be able to mock it (which means you can get started quickly mocking an old code base that wasn't written with TDD in mind), but it can't get around static calls.

**UPDATE**
Lets say you need to unit test a method `GenerateWidgetReports` that calls `ReportGenerator.GenerateReport`. You need to ensure `stuffToReportOn` contains only `Widget1` & `Widget2`. How do you code that test?

What you end up doing is having `GenerateWidgetReports` use a method called `GetStuffToReportOn`, you can test that, fine.   `GenerateWidgetReports` then just becomes glue that calls `GetStuffToReportOn` and passes it's result to `ReportGenerator.GenerateReport`.

However you still have no test for `GenerateWidgetReports`, because you can't call it without *actually* generating the report.

Ideally the class with `GenerateWidgetReports` takes an IReportGenerator object, you mock the `GenerateReport` method and test in there for `Widget1` & `Widget2`.

You can't do any of this with any Mocking tool if `GenerateReport` is static.

**Update 2**
I stand corrected, TypeMock can intercept and re-direct calls to static methods. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540239/mocking-static-methods-using-rhino-mocks/820351#820351)

Comment: What if I construct my own mock objects?  Can't I unit test it then?

Answer (score 1):

Other than difficulty in unit testing, you should ask yourself:

1. Do I make changes to the parameters? If so, how often?
2. Does the object need to have a state?
3. Do I need to keep the object around after the process?

If you determine that making it a static class works for you, you could also decide to go one step further and make an extension method:

```
public static class ReportExtension
{
    public static string GenerateReport(this List<SomeClass> stuffToReportOn)
    {
        string fileName = String.Empty;
        using(var reportDs = CreateDataSet(stuffToReportOn))
        {
            //do the stuff with the third party tool that 
            //creates the report.
            //Construct the filename.
            //Save the report.
        }
        return fileName;
    }

    private static TypedDataSetRequiredByThirdPartyLib CreateDataSet(List<SomeClass> reportItems)
    {
        //create the dataset, calling two other private methods
        //to build the tables/rows
    }
}
```

Pretty sure I have my formatting correct for an extension method.

### Edit:

You still have the issues of unit testing because code depends on this static method. Ultimately, you will have to decide on the pros and cons and make the decision yourself. I could be wrong, but if you were to unit test the dependent code with this as an instance class, you can gain some confidence that it should be fine as a static or extension method.

Comment: The problem isn't unit testing a simple static method, it's unit testing code that relies on that static method. Every time you create a static class you create a class with all the problems of a singleton, but without any of the (few) advantages a singleton can provide.

Comment: @Binary: With unit testing, I am mostly making reference to your post - agreeing that unit testing is more problematic because of the static method.

Comment: Apologies, I obviously misread "but I don't think that unit testing on something this simple should be problematic".

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it would make using your class a lot easier.