# how to create mock of static class using Rhino

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, static, rhino-mocks

I am using `Rhino.Mocks` to mock objects for unit testing my .net application. I want to mock a static class. If someone has idea of how to do this, please suggest.

Comment: static methods and classes are very difficult to test!

Comment: this has also been covered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/540239/mocking-static-methods-using-rhino-mocks

Comment: mocks are for creating instances that conform to some abstraction without the real implementation.  this is not something they were ever intended to do.  i get that you can do things like this with typemock and such, but it's getting away from the intent and is indicative of bigger problems in design.  if a static method is doing something with external dependencies such that you'd care to mock it, it probably shouldn't be a static method.

Answer (score 3):

Short answer : you can't.

You can wrap the static up in a facade object and then mock that which will probably acheive wwhat you want.

See [Mocking Static methods using Rhino.Mocks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/540239/mocking-static-methods-using-rhino-mocks)